# How to alternate row color and specify column color simultaneously in LyX

Tags: tables, lyx, colortbl

I'm trying to set column 0 of my table to gray as well alternate its row colors, for example:

[image]

I've managed to get the alternative row colors working by inserting the ERT before the table:

```
\rowcolors{0}{gray!15}{white}
```

However, adding the column LaTeX argument doesn't work:

```
>{\columncolor{gray!15}}c
```

Both work perfectly when used separately. Any ideas how I can get them working simultaneously?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `colortbl` draws the rows over the columns.

To overcome this behavior, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\rowcolors{0}{gray!15}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!15}}c|ccc|}
  \hline
    & a & b & c \\
  \hline
  1 &   &   &   \\
  2 &   &   &   \\
  3 &   &   &   \\
  4 &   &   &   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems as if `colortbl` also draws over the borders of the table, although the document prints out just fine. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: @Bataleon You're welcome. In regards of the borders, it is just an issue with the PDF viewer (LyX in your case). Try opening the produced PDF with another viewer.

Comment: Perfect. Using a different PDF viewer solved the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides a so-called `\CodeBefore` with built-in commands to color rows, columns and cells. The command `\rowcolors` available in that `\CodeBefore` has a key `cols` to limit the scope of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|ccc|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!15}{1}
  \columncolor{gray!15}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{}[cols=2-]
\Body
\Hline
    & a & b & c \\
\Hline
  1 \\
  2 \\
  3 \\
  4 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output will be perfect in all the PDF viewers.

[image: Output of the above code]

It's possible to have the same output with an alternative syntax, closer to the syntax provided by `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!15}}c|ccc|}[color-inside]
\Hline
\rowcolor{gray!15}
    & a & b & c \\
\Hline
  1 & \rowcolors{}{gray!15} \\
  2 \\
  3 \\
  4 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

In that code, the command `\rowcolors` will apply only to the columns greater than 2 because the command is issued in a cell of the second column.

The output is the same.